# Java Applet with Mysql ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, applet

I'm using java applet with mysql connection. I used Netbeans to build paths. When my applet works in localhost, I got an error.

```
Exception in thread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "setContextClassLoader")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.setContextClassLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:38)
```

I just use [mysql-applet Netbeans](http://ferdidolot.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/javaapplet-mysql-jdbc-tutorial-using-netbeans/). Can you help me ?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874996/java-applet-cant-access-mysql-via-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade your MySQL Connector/J to 5.1.26 this should be fixed. Previously there was a call to 'setContextClassLoader()' which was removed for other reasons. See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68556